# Debug an app using TCP

Tags: c++, qt, debugging

I am a total newbie and trying to debug an application which should receive a binary via TCP. When I launch it, it begins to listen several ports, I execute `cat myfile | nc port_number` in **another** terminal (apps terminal is busy) and the app runs. But I have no idea how to debug it in Qt creator. Everything I found on the Internet seems irrelevant to my problem.

Comment: What do you mean by debugging in QtCreator? What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: You might find some further help [here](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debugging.html)...

Comment: I'd simply like to launch a debugger and see what's happening when the app is running. I'm interested what's going on when the application parses the binary.

Comment: A good place to put a breakpoint would be where you're listening for new connections